# Set Max Connections on Thin server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, thin, connection

I'm running a rails web app through the 'Thin' server 1.2.8 on windows. When I start the server I noticed the message "Maximum connections set to 1024". I was wondering if its possible to manually set the maximum connections to another number? I looked through the help options and I only saw an option for changing the max persistent connections.

I did find a thread where someone was able to change the max connections using --max-conns but this option isnt available for the windows version apparently.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

in thin version 1.2.10 the default maximum number of connections is defined in the file
`<ruby_install_dir>/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.10/lib/thin/server.rb`

The value is called `DEFAULT_MAXIMUM_CONNECTIONS`.

Best regards,
Tim